# Visualization on Camera Image

Tags: android, camera, visualization

I want to implement visualization on camera image. For Example: if in camera view there is any wall and closed surface you can color that surface by choosing color from colorPicker. For a reference you can see  [dulux visualizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cethar.dcs.duluxcolour&hl=en).

Can anyone suggest me how to implement visualizer that I have explained above?

Answer (score 1):

`Dulux Visualizer` uses *image processing* capabilites. They extract whole element structure from the visualized picture, and manipulate it - in this case, paint it.

I would suggest you to look at `OpenCV`. It will provide all the necessary powerful image processing you need.

[OpenCV Tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)

[About OpenCV](http://opencv.org/about.html)

Comment: how to coloring the wall and object in image  before save.

Comment: I cannot provide you all details. You have to do little RnD by yourself for that :) First learn exactly what is OpenCV, then try to get an object when you tap it - just like "Magic Wand" in photoshop. After that, do whatever you want with that object.